# Instagram API: Get a list of recently tagged media returns only my own media

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, instagram

How to get all recenty tagged media from **all** users, as on this link https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/code/ ?

[Instagrap API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) returns media only from access_token's owner

**one more time:**

`requestUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tagName + '/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken;`

Request works fine BUT in response there are only my own media and I need to get media from all users by hashtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**
Your application currently have sandbox-mode. In sandbox-mode data is restricted by rule:

> "Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from
>   each sandbox user"

If you need full-access to API you have two ways:

1. Finish at least demo-version of your app and wait until it will be approved.
2. Use ACCESS_TOKEN generated for another, full-permission application. I.e. at my development stage I'm using ACCESS_TOKEN, generated [here](http://instagram.pixelunion.net/).

---

**Old text:**
As described [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) you must use REST-call:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

It returns exact same data as your url returns.

PS Also it returns data, which is necessary for pagination (to recieve older records with this tag). How to use it you can read [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

Comment: I'm sending a request and getting response BUT in response there are only my own media and I need to get media from all users by hashtag.

Comment: Use sent exactly such request?

Comment: Yes: requestUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tagName + '/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken;

Comment: Strange. Probably only this user uses tag which you request.

Comment: I don't think so :) In description I have attached the link

Comment: I called "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/code/media/recent?access_token=$accessToken" and I have entries from 19 other users - exact same as I see on web-page

Comment: May there be a problem with permissions for my instagram "client"?

Comment: Maybe. For requests above I'm using ACCESS_TOKEN generated from my 'just a user' account, not application access_token.
If you use ACCESS_TOKEN for your registered app, it could be in sandbox-mode or have strange permissions or something.

Comment: I can get ACCESS_TOKEN without application? O_o

Comment: Yes :) it is generated on OAuth so you can. I got it here: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

Comment: But for using OAuth you need client_id and client_secret which you can get only after registering an app. Seems like my app is in sandbox mode and an app on your link have full permissions

Comment: I'd rewrited answer :)